# Python - output not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is as follows:

```py
prompt = '\nPlease tell us your age'
prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you are finished)"

while True:
    age = input(prompt)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif int(age) < 3:

        print ('Your admission is free')
    elif int(age) > 3 < 12:
        print ('Your admission charge is $10')
    else:

        print ('Your admission charge is $15')

    break
```

Probably a simple answer, but when age entered greater than 12, returns 
'Your admission charge is $10' when  'Your admission charge is $15' is 
expected - Why ?

Comment: `elif 3 < int(age) < 12:`?

Answer (score 2):

When you have several condition after your `elif` statement, the syntax is a bit different :

```
while True:
   age = input(prompt)
   if age == 'quit':
       break
   elif int(age) < 3:
       print ('Your admission is free')

   elif (int(age) > 3) and (int(age) < 12):
   # Annother possibility :
   #elif 3 < int(age) < 6 : 
       print ('Your admission charge is $10')
   else:
       print ('Your admission charge is $15')

   break
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because its goint to else condition for example i put **13**, first condition is incorrect going to second, `13 < 3` **false**, going to third, `13 > 3` here true `< 12` here false, the condition is **false**, now going to `else` and make the stuff you want on this `else` in your case the `print`.

Good example of this situation is use of **assert**:

`assert 13 > 3 and 13 < 12`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use AND operator.

```
elif int(age) > 3 and int(age) < 12:
...
```

I also recommend casting the input right after you read it - you don't have to write int(age) every time :)

`age = int(input(prompt))`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
3 < age < 12

Your  int(age) > 3 < 12 is interpreted as
 int(age) > 3  &&  3 < 12
which is true for all ages over 3